# Puppet manifests class structure

Tags: puppet

When I was learning Puppet, I read somewhere that if you have subfolders or subdirectories within your Puppet module manifest folder, there should be an accompanying class file with the same name as the subfolder.

For example, in the scenario below there is a subfolder within manifests called `linux`, which contains additional classes, and there is a matching class within manifests called `linux.pp`.

```
[root@primary manifests]# pwd
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/firewall/manifests
[root@primary manifests]# tree
.
├── init.pp         # class firewall
├── linux
│   ├── archlinux.pp        # class firewall::linux::archlinux
│   ├── debian.pp       # class firewall::linux::debian
│   ├── gentoo.pp       # class firewall::linux::gentoo
│   └── redhat.pp       # class firewall::linux::redhat
├── linux.pp            # class firewall::linux
└── params.pp           # class firewall::params
```

So essentially if you're going to have a class named `modulename::subdirectory::classname` you should have a class called `modulename::subdirectory`. I was under the impression that this was standard convention, but I've seen individuals create classes within subfolders and include those without having an accompanying class for that subfolder at the root of the manifests folder. I looked in the Puppet documentation and Puppet style guide, but couldn't find any such convention. Am I crazy, or this a thing? Or is it just a thing under certain circumstances?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I read somewhere that if you have subfolders or subdirectories within your Puppet module manifest folder, there should be an accompanying class file with the same name as the subfolder.

> Am I crazy, or this a thing? Or is it just a thing under certain circumstances?

It is a reasonably common practice, and it makes enough sense organizationally for someone to write it down as a style recommendation (which is also a reason for it to be common).

But it is not a requirement of the Puppet manifest language, nor do I think it has ever been a recommendation of Puppet, Inc.'s own style guide, nor does it have a functional significance.

Personally, however, I find such a recommendation a bit tail-wagging-the-dog.  If it makes sense to group certain classes in a subdirectory, but there is nothing to configure that is common to them as a group, then I don't see any reason to add a class with the same name as the directory.

However, when grouping some classes in a subdirectory in fact makes sense, there usually are common aspects that would be well served by a class corresponding to the directory overall.  Sometimes, those common aspects include something like selecting which of the specific classes should be applied.

**Possibly, however, you are remembering something different**: a guideline to avoid lexically nesting classes.  That *is* [covered by the official style guide](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/style_guide.html#nested-classes-defined-types).  Unnesting such classes without changing their (fully-qualifed) names requires putting them in a subdirectory named after their original host class, which is what connects this to the alternative style point you asked about.